Continuity of a Family of Supermartingales
Suppose $\{Z_t(\alpha)\}_{\alpha}$ is a family of supermartingales of class (D) that is known to be jointly continuous, almost surely, as a function of $(t, \alpha)$. Say $(t, \alpha) \in [0, T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$. The Doob-Meyer decomposition states that for each $\alpha$, there exists an increasing predictable process $A_t(\alpha)$ and a martingale $M_t(\alpha)$, both of which are continuous in $t$, such that $$Z_t(\alpha) = M_t(\alpha) - A_t(\alpha)$$
almost surely (and the null set might depend on $\alpha$, of course). Does anyone know what can be said about the joint continuity of $M$ and $A$ in $(t, \alpha)$, if anything?

"Here's a definition and my random wondering, tell me stuff" is exactly the kind of question regularly closed for lacking context. Instead of wasting time to edit and complain, explain why this should be relevant to other people, what else you have hypothesised and considered, in what circumstances this would help you beyond just getting an answer to the question.

This is potentially useful for the same reason continuity (in time) of the usual Doob-Meyer decomposition is. Suppose you have a collection of models and you want to say something about their continuity not just in time but in some other variable on which they all depend. It is a very natural question and I am surprised there is basically no literature about it, which is why I asked. I'm sure there is no changing your mind, but folks here being so fussy about this sort of thing is toxic imo.

So, put that in the question, then you won't get close votes. Calling it fussy to have standards and enforce them is extremely rude; one could just as easily call a user precious for editing a rant into a post instead of simply fixing the issue.

Having standards which suppress discussion about (nontrivial) math questions is toxic, in my opinion. I would understand the standard if it was applied to a question a weak undergraduate would ask, of the variety: "how do I prove this obviously continuous thing is continuous from the definition of continuity". This does not apply to this question. I am not being extremely rude. I am pointing out a standard that is, again in my opinion, entirely stupid. There is no issue to be fixed here, other than this broken standard, hence the "rant".
